# short commands are not working in customized wish shell

Tags: tcl

I have a customized in version of wish 8.6 shell with own environment loaded.
The issue is in native wish shell, short command work.
eg. `packa r xxx` for package require or `stri e $str1 $str2` for string comparison.

But the same thing when i run in my customized shell, it says

> invalid command name "packa"

But it works for the options for the command, as `package re` works for requiring the package.

What could be the possible cause, that wish is unable to resolve command name?
I know it it's bit difficult to answer for a customized shell but if someone could share probable causes based of logics, that would be of great help.

Comment: What do you get with: info  commands p*?

Comment: (mywish) % info commands p*

`panedwindow pwd pid pack proc place pkg_mkIndex package puts`

Comment: I wish my wish worked like your wish.

Comment: Wish completed... :) by setting tcl_interactive to 1
Now my wish is same as you wish :P

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're not setting the global `tcl_interactive` to 1. That enables expansion of abbreviated command names as well as calling external programs without an explicit `exec` and a few other things (all of which is done in the `unknown` command handler procedure, or things it calls; if you want to customise things instead of working like `tclsh` does, look there).

Handling of unique prefixes of subcommand names is entirely separate.